# WD blue hard drive not showing up on my Linux system

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I have a `wd blue 1TB 5400 rpm` hard drive Made of Date `17 Jun 2018`. Model `WD10SPZX`.

The hard drive does not show up on Linux neither Windows. Trying to install a windows and/or Linux OS, the drive does not show up in Linux to install the OS and on the Windows OS installer it shows up as 0mb. When I boot up to the bios, I can see the hard drive in the bios. I even bought a sata to usb cable and I tested the cable with another hard drive and the other hard drive shows up on my current Arch-linux. But, when I connect the WD drive with the sata to usb cable it still does not show up. I touch the wd hard drive and I can feel it running without making any noise.

Is it a driver problem or the drive failed?

`dmesg` output (the hard drive message shows up after like 1 or 2 minutes. And I heard a sound from the laptop like if a new usb device has been connected):

```
[  538.938930] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  539.080643] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  539.080650] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[  539.080654] usb 1-3: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
[  539.080658] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: JMicron
[  539.080661] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[  539.082560] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  539.083427] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[  539.744557] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [^^^GFX0.AFN2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180810/psargs-330)
[  539.744598] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._QC9, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180810/psparse-514)
[  540.097082] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD10 SPZX-24Z10            PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[  540.098361] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  540.098533] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 72057594037927936 512-byte logical blocks: (36.9 EB/32.0 EiB)
[  540.098820] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  540.098824] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[  540.099114] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  540.099119] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  540.101909] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  540.739769] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [^^^GFX0.AFN2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180810/psargs-330)
[  540.739781] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._QC9, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180810/psparse-514)
[  540.877095] audit: type=1130 audit(1564103965.766:74): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-hostnamed comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  541.740767] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [^^^GFX0.AFN2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180810/psargs-330)
[  541.740800] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._QC9, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180810/psparse-514)
[  542.740993] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [^^^GFX0.AFN2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180810/psargs-330)
```

This msg keep showing up and make the output so long:

```
[  541.740800] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC._QC9, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180810/psparse-514)
    [  542.740993] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [^^^GFX0.AFN2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180810/psargs-330)
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the relevant part of `dmesg` on Linux that shows what happens when the kernel tries to recognize your hard drive. If your motherboard supports hot-plug SATA, you can also disconnect the drive, type `dmesg`, remember the last line, connect the drive again, and the new lines are the relevant ones. The most likely cause is the something on the drive is broken. A driver problem is very very unlikely.

Comment: @dirkt thanks for your reply. I added the `dmesg` output to my question.

Comment: Looks like that drive has failed.

Comment: @NasirRiley Is it possible to know the reason from the log above? For example: electricity surcharge...

Comment: No. `dmesg` isn't going to tell you exactly why a hardware component failed. It only contains information about what happened since it was plugged into the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a SATA harddrive in an enclosure that offers an USB port. Inside the enclosure, the SATA drive connects to a chip ("USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge"), that translates SATA to USB. This chip is manufactured by JMicron.

When you connect the drive via USB, the kernel asks the drive for some basic parameters, including capacity. However, the answers it gets indicate an error, which usually indicates a "very big drive". Then it tries to use a command appropriate for big drives, and gets a ridiculous amount of capacity back.

The means:

1) Your harddisk controller chip is broken; or

2) The JMicron chip, which is known to sometimes have trouble, doesn't translate the hard drive's answer correctly to USB.

In the first case, there's nothing you can do.

To test the second case, open the enclosure, take out the hard drive, and directly connect it to SATA on your motherboard. If it works that way, you can either use it as a SATA drive, or you need to buy a new enclosure with a chip that works for this hard drive. No, I don't know which brand or model you'd need for that.